# what is the difference between a featured article and a single article in joomla?

Tags: joomla

Can anyone make me understand the difference between a featured article and a single article in joomla?
I have created two articles with same content, one as featured false and another feature true, and linked them with two menus. Both the aricles showing same. So I can't understand the difference between them. Please make me understand the difference between these two types of articles.

Answer (score 0):

The Featured Articles option is useful for displaying several articles which aren't necessarily all in the same category.

Answer (score 0):

A Feature Article is an option that have any article in order to mark it and display it in a link, in a menu, in a module or by default in Home page.

It is useful to display new content in Home by default or to make an article highlighted.